# Issue in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
table 1:userdetails with fields:uid,mobile,name

table 2:accountdetails with fields:uid,savings,balance
```

Where uid is common and primary key in both tables.
Now Iam trying to get mobile,savings values from both tables where uid =1 how can we get.I tried below but didnt worked.

```
 select mobile,savings 
 from userdetails,accountdetails 
 where userdetails.uid='1'AND 
      userdetails.uid = accountdetails.uid
```

Please can some one help

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What was wrong with the results?

Comment: Also, you might want to use the more modern _join_ syntax instead of comma separated tables.

Comment: comma separated tables in that where condtion work if you have matching data on  uid in tables, did you check in both tables having uid 1 available ?

Answer (score 0):

Use join

select mobile,savings 
 from userdetails join accountdetails on  userdetails.uid = accountdetails.uid
 where userdetails.uid='1'

Answer (score 0):

More modern version using the **JOIN** syntax:

```
SELECT 
    a.`mobile`,
    b.`savings`
FROM `userdetails` a
JOIN `accountdetails` b
ON a.`uid` = b.`uid`
WHERE a.`uid` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should probably look like this:

```
 select ud.mobile, ad.savings 
 from userdetails ud left join
      accountdetails ad
      on ud.uid = ad.uid
 where ud.uid = 1;
```

Notes:

- Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases and qualify all columns names.
- The `left join` keeps all rows, even if there is no match in the second table.  That might be your problem.
- I am assuming that `uid` is actually a number.  Don't put numbers around numeric constants.

Comment: @user7350714 . . . Such a comment is not helpful.   How did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on your error display to show you exactly what line is causing the issue.

```html
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
    SELECT `ud`.`mobile`, `ad`.`savings` 
    FROM `userdetails` `ud`
    INNER JOIN `accountdetails` `ad` ON `ud`.`uid` = `ad`.`uid` 
    WHERE `us`.`uid` = 1
```